# how to dynamically add column in datagrid based on the datatable in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

My datatable will give result as below

```
Particaulars    Jan_16  Feb_16  Mar_16  Apr_16  May_16  
Purchase        1169.48 328.45  7.00    60.96   4.28    
Freight         25.00   30.00   15.00   75.00   46.37   
Insurance       728.65  704.52  13.40   80.08   85.43
```

Columns may increase based on some condition.
then How do i show this data in **datagridview**?
Plz help me

Comment: Set AutoGenerateColumns = "true"

Comment: Is it Windows Forms or WebForms?

Comment: it is webForms. Any sample code pls

Comment: Thanks Sami.. it is working..